# How to remove spaces between two given characters from a string using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to remove all spaces between letters "a" and "b" in a text using sed.

waaa bbb => waaabbb
a b a b abb b => abababbb
z aaa bn i => z aaabn i

I know how to find these strings in a text using regular expressions:

```
grep -E '[ab]+[ ]+[ab]' file.txt
```

I also know how to do it using four commands:

```
sed -E 's/a a/aa/' file.txt
sed -E 's/a b/ab/' file.txt
sed -E 's/b a/ba/' file.txt
sed -E 's/b b/bb/' file.txt
```

But is possible to do that using only one sed command?

Sample input:

```
Lorem ipsum wa baaaaaaa baaa dolor sit amet,
consectetur b b ba aaaa b adipiscing elit
abba a g baa p a aaaa s
```

Desirable output:

```
Lorem ipsum wabaaaaaaabaaa dolor sit amet,
consectetur bbbaaaaabadipiscing elit
abbaa g baa p aaaaa s
```

Comment: Enabling the `-P` option (I think), I believe you can use `(?<=[ab]) +(?=[ab])`

Comment: @ctwheels sed has no `-P` option.

Comment: @EdMorton `grep` does though

Comment: @ctwheels the OP asked for a **sed** command to remove spaces between specific characters. That's not something you can do with grep even if the OP hadn't explicitly asked for sed.

Comment: @EdMorton well that’s why it was a suggestion written as a comment and not an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a label and a conditional test:

```
sed ':a;s/\([ab]\)  *\([ab]\)/\1\2/g;ta' file
```

or using ERE:

```
sed -E ':a;s/([ab]) +([ab])/\1\2/g;ta' file
```

The test `t` jumps to the label `a` as long as something is replaced with the previous command.

More informations about sed features: [grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

---

You can also do it without a test since two global replacements suffice. You only have to rewrite the replacement command:

```
sed 's/\([ab]\)  *\([ab]\)/\1\2/g;s/\([ab]\)  *\([ab]\)/\1\2/g' file
```

or using ERE:

```
sed -E 's/([ab]) +([ab])/\1\2/g;s/([ab]) +([ab])/\1\2/g' file
```